# DocuSign SOAP API with access tokens

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP based API calls to create DocuSign envelopes. I am using legacy authentication method in which I pass the userid and password of the DocuSign user that I want to create envelopes with. If I want to use the new authentication method - oAuth Authorization code grant, do I have to use the REST based API calls from DocuSign?

I could not find a way to include the access token in the authentication header that I am using in the legacy authentication method.

Please advise,

Thanks,

Minal

Comment: Indeed, the [DocuSign SOAP documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Introduction+Changes/Authentication.htm%3FTocPath%3DAuthentication%7C_____0) doesn't mention the possibility to use OAuth with the SOAP API. Also, looking at the [xsd](https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/schema/dsx.xsd), I can't find any elements related to OAuth or Access Token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DocuSign oauth flows are only supported for the rest api.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.